# In Google Analytics what is the relationship between “Event” and “Site Usage” in behavior / events / pages / report

Tags: google-analytics

0

In behavior / events / pages there are 2 options. "Event" and "Site Usage". What is the relationship between these two settings.

When i select a page such as "/payment" and action "MyAction" i get the below results.

"Event" view: Total events = 3,625
"Site Usage" view: Sessions = 4
In the business logic of our application these 2 values should be closer together. Noticably, the "Site Usage" only having 4 sessions looks suspicious.

To give a broader outline what i'm trying to achieve. I'd like to know the page duration of a user on "/payment" and has the action "MyAction" over the past month.